# Socket.io how to get id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

How to get Id (unical key) from server (socket.io)?

i tired with `clients[socket.id] = socket;`

but i get error

```
 connections property is deprecated. use getconnections() method
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Could you provide us with some more code to further assist you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ID of socket in socket.io by simply:

```
var id = socket.id;
```